# Ubuntu 16.04 - apt v: 1.2.32 - Returns E: Sub-process http received signal 4

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

Thanks in advance for any help and anyone coming here for same problem I hope you find what you need <3

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago and learning to use it, fresh from a Windows-lifer so pretty close to full noob ;)

I noticed this issue while trying to apt-get ssh. It seems that when I try to do anything with apt it returns this error..

```
$ sudo apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 4.
```

Here are the history and term logs for apt : /var/log/apt

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fBTTDtRfC3/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NFV9HQJNbG/

I've been unable to find any error reports or fixes online for "signal 4" despite implementing my best google-fu. Given that I am sorry if this turns out to be a duplicate.

My current best guess is that the last command with apt for getting nedit caused the issue and therefore >> libmotif-common << is my suspected culprit.

It feaures only in the last entries in both the apt log and history files and I noticed in fixes for other similar-ish errors that there was a common thread of lib files being the issue.

Massively appreciate any feed back!!
Gheko

Answer (score 0):

Okay, fixed it. TL;DR --> Downgrade apt.

I ran "apt show apt" to find the version I had installed is 1.2.32.

I then web-browsed to http://packages.ubuntu.com and searched for "apt" and found version 1.2.29 to be the most recent Xenial version (Xenial apparently being the version of Ubuntu I have, although since it's a customized Xenial for Chrome, I'm guessing it's got a newer apt version, that has this bug).

I manually downloaded it, and then manually installed it with

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_1.2.29ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

When I then tried to run "sudo apt update", I got an error that apt-utils or some other piece required the newer apt, but that I might try "apt-get -f install". I tried the latter:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That wanted to remove apt-utils and ubuntu-minimal; I allowed the removal.

Then I was able to successfully "sudo apt upgrade" and "sudo apt install firefox" and "sudo apt install aptitude". I think my problem is fixed. At least for today.

/Kent